# "Bring to front" a GTK/C application on OS-X

Tags: c, macos, gtk

I'm developping an application running on GNU/Linux and OS-X.
On linux, if I start the application with command line I have no problem. On OS-X, the application start but not on "front". I must click on the icon in the dock to see the application. Is there a way to bring an application on front at start.

Comment: Have you tried `gtk_window_set_urgency_hint ()`?

Comment: OK, I did it thanks to you. In Glade I've set the property "urgency_hint" to TRUE. And it is working. So you're right. Thank you so much.

Comment: Oh no. Sorry. It does not work

Comment: If `gtk_window_present()` doesn't work its perhaps a Gtk on OSX bug, what Gtk version?

Comment: gtk_window_present dors not work indeed. And I use the last stable version.

Comment: In my opinion you should provide a [MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that creates a window and exhibits that problem.

Comment: I can give the link to the full application. This is an opensource software that can be installed through homebrew.

Comment: Ah, I see now you are using Homebrew to run someone else's app. My answer still applies, but now applying that answer is harder... It is a good question, and I wonder if the Homebrew devs themselves have tackled it before.

Comment: I think that generally homebrew should be used for not GUI programs, while homeberw-cask (https://caskroom.github.io/) is intended to be used for that. homebrew-cask uses a bundle but building an .app bundle is not easy for me as I do not really have OSX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue has to do with OS X's process launching model, not with GTK+. The only correct and sustainable way to fix this is to use an `.app` bundle.

When running an app with OS X, the app needs to explicitly ask to be brought to front after setting its activation policy using the `NSApplication` method `activateIgnoringOtherApps:`. However, when Launch Services launches an `.app` bundle, it takes care of this automatically. Having an explicit call to `activateIgnoringOtherApps:` in your code will just make things more complicated for you to get everything right. [I asked this question a while ago; the answer there explains in more detail.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25318524/what-exactly-should-i-pass-to-nsapp-activateignoringotherapps-to-get-my-appl)

By the same rationale, GTK+ itself does not make this call either. You can add this call yourself right before `gtk_main()` if you want for development, but for actually distributing your apps, it's better to leave things as is.

Comment: Thank you. This answer is very helpful.